# How can set text for Jtextfield from the array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, static

I have a problem when doing my project. 
I connect my database and get database about the value of food. I put all of the value to the array (public static array). But I wondering that anyway can I set the text of the textfield by the value from the array?
Here is my declaring array:

```
public static String[] fp;
```

----------- main()

```
fp = new String[9];
            try {
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(get_food_price);
                int i =0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                    fp[i] = rs.getString(1);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

----------- private void initialize() {

```
food1_price.setText(fp[1]);
```

------------ It's not working with fp[1] (array) but It do work with normal string like "acb" or "asdsa"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, as is, your code is unreadable. Are you sure that `fp` has values? And that you're not declaring it twice? If it doesn't have those values, then the error has nothing to do with the database and thus that code is irrelevant. Please post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue. Narrow it down to database issue or UI issue.

Comment: Post the full class or it's compilable part at least. What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
    MySQLConnection db = new MySQLConnection();
    Connection connect = db.getmysql_connection();
    String query="SELECT * FROM "; //Your query
    Statement stmt = (Statement) connect.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    int i=0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        fp[i] = rs.getString(1);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: oh, it's working, thank you very much, I appreciate it!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you select is as correct answer?